# Parsing Adafruit Ultimate GPS in Arduino

Tags: arduino

Im new in Arduino programming and i have quite a problem which is save longitude and latitude values of my new Adafruit Ultimate GPS Breakout. im using the tutorial giving in the website then i tried to apply parsing code in the library
Open up the File→Examples→Adafruit_GPS→parsing sketch and upload it to the Arduino. Then open up the serial monitor.
i got the results in my serial monitor as shown in the attached file (i highlighted my question in the snap below)

Im trying to save the values of my location in the degree which is appear in the serial monitor as
Location (in degrees, works with Google Maps): 32.5011, 44.4499

A part of the standard code for display result is:

```
Serial.print("\nTime: ");
    Serial.print(GPS.hour, DEC); Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(GPS.minute, DEC); Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(GPS.seconds, DEC); Serial.print('.');
    Serial.println(GPS.milliseconds);
    Serial.print("Date: ");
    Serial.print(GPS.day, DEC); Serial.print('/');
    Serial.print(GPS.month, DEC); Serial.print("/20");
    Serial.println(GPS.year, DEC);
    Serial.print("Fix: "); Serial.print((int)GPS.fix);
    Serial.print(" quality: "); Serial.println((int)GPS.fixquality);
    if (GPS.fix) {
      Serial.print("Location: ");
      Serial.print(GPS.latitude, 4); Serial.print(GPS.lat);
      Serial.print(", ");
      Serial.print(GPS.longitude, 4); Serial.println(GPS.lon);
      Serial.print("Location (in degrees, works with Google Maps): ");
      Serial.print(GPS.latitudeDegrees, 4);
      Serial.print(", ");
      Serial.println(GPS.longitudeDegrees, 4);
      Serial.print("Speed (knots): "); Serial.println(GPS.speed);
      Serial.print("Angle: "); Serial.println(GPS.angle);
      Serial.print("Altitude: "); Serial.println(GPS.altitude);
      Serial.print("Satellites: "); Serial.println((int)GPS.satellites);
```

the results is shown below
[image]
next i tried to define 2 variable in order to copy the longitude and latitude value by adding simple code after the Serial.println(GPS.longitudeDegrees, 4); as shown below

```
Serial.print("Location (in degrees, works with Google Maps): ");
      Serial.print(GPS.latitudeDegrees, 4);
      Serial.print(", ");
      Serial.println(GPS.longitudeDegrees, 4);
      lat1= (GPS.latitudeDegrees, 4);
      lon1=(GPS.longitudeDegrees, 4);
      Serial.println (lat1);
      Serial.println (lon1);
      delay (500);
```

then i got only number four in my lat1 and lon1 value in serial monitor

[image]

then i edit the code by removing number 4 from it as shown below

```
Serial.print("Location (in degrees, works with Google Maps): ");
  Serial.print(GPS.latitudeDegrees, 4);
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.println(GPS.longitudeDegrees, 4);
  lat1= GPS.latitudeDegrees;
  lon1=GPS.longitudeDegrees;
  Serial.println (lat1);
  Serial.println (lon1);
  delay (500);
```

then i got only 2 number after the dot
32.5011 → 32.50
44.4499 → 44.45
as shown in the attached below
[image]
so im asking how can i save the full number in my lon1 and lat1 because i need these number for further analysis
BTW i tried to defie lon1, lat1 as float, double and still same issue just 2 number after digit i got
thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point numbers have an infinite number of decimal places.  When you print them it will only print 2 unless you specify with the second parameter how many to print.

For example:

```
float x = 67.1234

Serial.print(x); // will print 67.12
Serial.print(x,3); // will print 67.123
Serial.print(x, 4); // will print 67.1234
Serial.print(x,6);  // will print 67.123400
```

So what you are seeing is just how many places  you told it to print.  But the variable always has the whole number with an infinite number of decimal places.

Now with floats on an Arduino only the first 6 or 7 decimal places will be accurate.  But the number itself has an infinite number of digits after the decimal if you want to print them.

Also note that the second parameter is only doing something in the print statement.  Lots of people will try to do this:

```
float x = 67.1234 , 2;
```

thinking that this will somehow save a number with only 2 digits of precision, but this isn't the case.  In this case it would just save the number 2.  As you saw in your experiment.  This is how the comma operator works.  It's only in the print function that you get to specify.  Again, the actual number itself has an infinite number of decimal places you can print.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i appreciate that.
Actually i the real problem is not printing, as when I print the output using serial monitor, there is no problem, but I want to store the resulting values in a variable in order to send it later, when I put the output with a variable for the purpose of storing things do not go well.

Comment: No, it stores fine.  But when you print it to look at it then it defaults to only showing you 2 of the decimal places.  Change "Serial.println (lat1);" to "Serial.println (lat1, 6);" and see what happens.

Comment: I want to store the value in a specific variable, then this value I send it using a wireless transmitter for the purpose of applying the Haversine formula to calculate the distances between two devices, so it is not important for me to display the value in the Serial Monitor, but the important thing is to transmit the entire data through the transmitter for both lat1 and lon1. If i send lat1 and lon1 what did you expect to receive at the receiver? since it is look by defaults to only showing me 2 of the decimal places.

Comment: Serial.print sends data.  It’s not about display.  Look I promise when you store that number all the digits are stored.  You just don’t know that because when you displayed it you didn’t display them all.  But they are there.  They are stored.  It’s not about display.   WHEN YOU SAVE THAT NUMBER TO A FLOAT VARIABLE IT HAS AN INFINITE NUMBER OF DECIMAL PLACES!!!   They’re all there.  I don’t know how else you can prove that to yourself besides displaying it.  How else will you know what is stored unless you see the number?   It’s all there.  It is.  What do you want that you’re not getting?

Comment: There is no such thing as storing a number with only two decimal places.  You have fooled yourself into thinking it only has two because that’s what you saw when you printed it.  I’ve already told you why that happened.  It isn’t because those digits aren’t stored.  It’s just because when you printed them you didn’t print them all.  That’s the only reason you didn’t see them.  But they’re there.  All of them. Just try displaying them and you’ll see that they’re all there.

Comment: Transmitting then to the receiver will be the same issue as displaying.  When you transmit them you need to decide how many places you want to transmit.  Or you can break the float variable into its four constituent bytes and send them and reassemble on the other end and.  Either way the whole thing got stored.  What do you need to see to convince you of that?

Comment: I would like to thank you for this sufficient and ample explanation. You have answered all my doubts, my friend, and I want appreciate that. In this case, I can send this data in order to receive it from the other device and apply the calculation for finding the distance between two points using longitude and latitude.